Getting /home/ubuntu/NAS: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member' - Accessing files on a synology NAS drive
I'm trying to follow this https://kb.synology.com/en-uk/DSM/tutorial/How_can_I_recover_data_from_my_DiskStation_using_a_PC#x_anchor_encryptedvolume
But I get this when I try to mount
mount /dev/md127 /home/ubuntu/nas
mount: /home/ubuntu/nas: uknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.

